# Tensorflow: load multiple images to process (Python)

Tags: python, image, tensorflow

I am working on a Tensorflow project (https://github.com/niektemme/tensorflow-mnist-predict) and I am in front of a problem.
In the file named `predict_2.py` there is a block of code which load an image..

```
def imageprepare(argv):
    """
    This function returns the pixel values.
    The input is a png file location.
    """

    im = Image.open(argv).convert('L')
    width = float(im.size[0])
    height = float(im.size[1])
    newImage = Image.new('L', (28, 28), (255)) #creates white canvas of 28x28 pixels

    if width > height: #check which dimension is bigger
        #Width is bigger. Width becomes 20 pixels.
        nheight = int(round((20.0/width*height),0)) #resize height according to ratio width
        if (nheight == 0): #rare case but minimum is 1 pixel
            nheigth = 1  
        # resize and sharpen
        img = im.resize((20,nheight), Image.ANTIALIAS).filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
        wtop = int(round(((28 - nheight)/2),0)) #caculate horizontal pozition
        newImage.paste(img, (4, wtop)) #paste resized image on white canvas
    else:
        #Height is bigger. Heigth becomes 20 pixels. 
        nwidth = int(round((20.0/height*width),0)) #resize width according to ratio height
        if (nwidth == 0): #rare case but minimum is 1 pixel
            nwidth = 1
         # resize and sharpen
        img = im.resize((nwidth,20), Image.ANTIALIAS).filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
        wleft = int(round(((28 - nwidth)/2),0)) #caculate vertical pozition
        newImage.paste(img, (wleft, 4)) #paste resized image on white canvas

    #newImage.save("sample.png")

    tv = list(newImage.getdata()) #get pixel values

    #normalize pixels to 0 and 1. 0 is pure white, 1 is pure black.
    tva = [ (255-x)*1.0/255.0 for x in tv] 
    return tva
```

Normally, I execute all the code (not just this one) in CMD so the program works.
What I would like to do now is to load multiple images (maybe from a different folder) and not just to pass the argv in the console which load only one image at the time.

What I previously thought was to create an array/list of images and then to put it instead of `im` variable. It doesn't work...

Can someone help ? Documentation on Tensorflow (and even the project itself) are very poor (atleast for me).

Thank you.

EDIT:

Here is full code

```
"""Predict a handwritten integer (MNIST expert).

Script requires
1) saved model (model2.ckpt file) in the same location as the script is run from.
(requried a model created in the MNIST expert tutorial)
2) one argument (png file location of a handwritten integer)

Documentation at:
http://niektemme.com/ @@to do
"""

#import modules
import sys
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
from PIL import Image as PImage
import os
from os import listdir
from datetime import datetime
from os import listdir

def predictint(imvalue):
    """
    This function returns the predicted integer.
    The input is the pixel values from the imageprepare() function.
    """

    # Define the model (same as when creating the model file)
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

    def weight_variable(shape):
      initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
      return tf.Variable(initial)

    def bias_variable(shape):
      initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
      return tf.Variable(initial)

    def conv2d(x, W):
      return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

    def max_pool_2x2(x):
      return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')   

    W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
    b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])

    x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,28,28,1])
    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
    h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

    W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
    b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

    h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
    h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

    W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
    b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

    h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
    h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

    W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
    b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

    y_conv=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    """
    Load the model2.ckpt file
    file is stored in the same directory as this python script is started
    Use the model to predict the integer. Integer is returend as list.

    Based on the documentatoin at
    https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/variables/index.html
    """
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)
        saver.restore(sess, "model2.ckpt")
        #print ("Model restored.")

        prediction=tf.argmax(y_conv,1)

        return prediction.eval(feed_dict={x: [imvalue],keep_prob: 1.0}, session=sess)


def imageprepare(argv):
    """
    This function returns the pixel values.
    The input is a png file location.
    """

    im = Image.open(argv).convert('L')
    width = float(im.size[0])
    height = float(im.size[1])
    newImage = Image.new('L', (28, 28), (255)) #creates white canvas of 28x28 pixels

    if width > height: #check which dimension is bigger
        #Width is bigger. Width becomes 20 pixels.
        nheight = int(round((20.0/width*height),0)) #resize height according to ratio width
        if (nheight == 0): #rare case but minimum is 1 pixel
            nheigth = 1  
        # resize and sharpen
        img = im.resize((20,nheight), Image.ANTIALIAS).filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
        wtop = int(round(((28 - nheight)/2),0)) #caculate horizontal pozition
        newImage.paste(img, (4, wtop)) #paste resized image on white canvas
    else:
        #Height is bigger. Heigth becomes 20 pixels. 
        nwidth = int(round((20.0/height*width),0)) #resize width according to ratio height
        if (nwidth == 0): #rare case but minimum is 1 pixel
            nwidth = 1
         # resize and sharpen
        img = im.resize((nwidth,20), Image.ANTIALIAS).filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
        wleft = int(round(((28 - nwidth)/2),0)) #caculate vertical pozition
        newImage.paste(img, (wleft, 4)) #paste resized image on white canvas

    #newImage.save("sample.png")

    tv = list(newImage.getdata()) #get pixel values

    #normalize pixels to 0 and 1. 0 is pure white, 1 is pure black.
    tva = [ (255-x)*1.0/255.0 for x in tv] 
    return tva
    #print(tva)  


def main(argv):
    """
    Main function.
    """
    imvalue = imageprepare(argv)
    predint = predictint(imvalue)
    print (predint[0]) #first value in list

    timestr = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S-%f")
    file = open('B' + timestr + '.txt', 'w')
    file.write('Causale: ' + str(predint))
    file.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('C:\\Users\\Wkgrp\\Desktop\\numeri\\4.jpg')
```

Comment: You simply have to loop over the images.

Comment: Yes, but immagine that: to run all the code, I have to give an argument in CMD. That argv is right the image I give, just one at the time. Do you know how to do it ? How to put it in a loop ? Do I have to delete the arg ?

Comment: Just pass the foldername as an argument and iterate the images in that folder in python. There are plenty of questions on SO on how to do this.

Comment: Just passing the folder with images won't work. I edit with full code so you can see...